# Spring don't load html template from resources

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I can stop in debug inside the controller, but the method returns the string "greeting" not the template.

**src/main/java/controllers/GreetingController.java**

```
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name,
                           Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

**src/main/resources/templates/greeting.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1 th:text="|Hello, ${name}!|"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try @Controller instead of @RestController ?

Comment: That might do it. RestControllers return objects, not views.